# $2$-Sylow subgroups and Dihedral groups

Tags: sylow-theory

Let $D_{2n}$ be the Dihedral group of order $2n$. If $n$ is odd, find $n_2$ the number of $2$-sylow subgroups of $D_{2n}$

**Here's the solution**

$|D_{2n}| = 2n $ and $ 2$ does not divide $n$ therefore the $2$-Sylows will be of order 2. (**Why is that implication true?**)

$D_{2n}$ contains $n$ symetries, therefore, $n_2 = n \equiv 1  (\mod 2)$ (**Here I understand that using the third Sylow theorem, we have that that $n_2 \equiv 1 (\mod 2)$ but I don't know how one can conclude that $n_p = n$**)

Comment: If n is odd, then it's prime decomposition doesn't contain 2

Comment: @Fakemistake what does that show?

Comment: $|D_{2n}|=p_1\cdots p_r=2n$ is even, thus we can assume $p_1=2$. It's possible, that there is an $i\geq 2$ bounded by $r$, such that $p_i=2$, but this is impossible since $p_1=2$ does not divide $n=p_2\cdots p_r$, thus a $p_1$-sylowgroup has order $2^1$. This is an explanation to the first question, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the visualisation of dihedral group.

It contains $2n$ elements, $s_1,s_2,s_3,\dots s_n$ and $r_1,r_2,\dots ,r_n$ , where $s_i$ stands for the symmetries of a regular $n$-gon and and $r_i$ stands for the rotations of a regular $n$-gon.

Note that each of $s_i$ has order=$2$  and no $r_i$ have order equal to $2$, so the number of elements of order $2$ is $n$.

Now, what is the definition of $2$-sylow subgroups?
Subgroups that have the order of highest power of $2$ in the prime factorization of the order of the group.

Here order of the group is $2n$ and n is odd so the two sylow subgroups have order equal to $2$, and number of such elements is $n$.